# Email From Access Through Outlook, Allow Recipient To Answer Survey From Message

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm trying to have an email sent from Access through Outlook containing two buttons that will report back to the Access Database.

Is this possible?  And I know how to have an email send, I just don't know anything about adding a button to the outlook message (if that's even possible).

If this is not possible then I'll just have a notification sent out and the user will have to open a front end form and click accept or deny manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook macros are stored in outlook templates, and don't seem to be well-suited for distribution.

AFAIK there is not any support for including a macro in an `Outlook.MailItem` -- this is the functionality you're describing, like, adding `FormControls` (command buttons, etc?) to the mail, which will execute a subroutine that reports back to your DB.

You might look in to using the Voting Buttons. These can be added to your mail item, assuming you have an object variable like `mItem` to represent the `Outlook.MailItem`:

```
mItem.VotingOptions = "Yes;No;Maybe"
```

When clicked, you will receive a response email.

You can probably use VBA from Access to periodically query your inobx, parse these received emails, and add to the DB.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to add controls.  Basically an approve control and a denied control and the emails will go out to managers.  I was hoping it could reply back to Access, but I like the idea of checking incoming replies in an inbox.  I will have to do a bit more research on VBA in Outlook, because I'm only familar with Access.  Is your `mItem.VotingOptions` something you placed in the `.MailItem` in Access then?  Thanks

Comment: No. `.VotingOptions` is one of the *properties* of a `MailItem` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221825(v=office.11).aspx)) .  As I mentioned above, if you have an *object variable* `mItem`..." so `mItem` is just an object variable representing an `Outlook.MailItem`.  You can't add controls with event-handlers. It just can't be done because that is not where .bas modules can be stored.  Ultimately, you would do the vba *from* access, and just add a reference to the Outlook object library, which would allow you to control Outlook from within your Access subroutines.